# how to get Array of values from consul in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I have multiple host values according to different markets how to fetch all those in spring-boot to create a bean.
I have tried with

```
@value("#{${app.host}}")
private String[] host;
```

consul values

```
app:
  host:
    hostone: 'localhost:8080'
    hosttwo: 'abc:8089'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain an array whit the following annotation

```java
@Value("${app.host}")
private String[] host;
```

but your yml should be

```yaml
app:
  host:
    - localhost:8080
    - abc:8089
```

or you can get

```
@Value("${app.host}")
private Map<String,String> host;
```

and keep your YML file as-is.